# How to disable stepping in disassembly mode in IAR Workbench?

Tags: ide, iar

I'm running IAR Embedded Workbench 8.30.1.17148.  When I enter debug / step mode, it opens the disassembly window and starts stepping at the disassembly level -- not at the source code level.

I can close the disassembly window and restart the program, but like an unwelcome guest, the disassembly window opens again and it steps at the disassembly level.

How do I convince IAR Workbench that I really want to step at source level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was getting so annoyed by this same behavior, I searched IAR FAQ to no avail, but got a speedy response from their support:

In regard to your question about the Assembly Window:
1. When the IDE is opened you can close the Assemblt window by selecting the "x"
on the upper right corner of the assembly window.
Than you select the "C" editor section. If you single step now it will stay only in the
"C" section and the assemblt window will stay close.
2. If this isn't the behaviour you expereince please do the following:
1. Highlight the project you are workign with.
2. Right click and select "open containing folder"
3. Exit the IDE
4. In the project folder directory that is open rename the "setting" directory to "setting.save"
5. Open the IDe again.

So it is so simple the resolution that worked for me: close the automatically popped-up disassembly, click in the source code window so cursor is blinking there, then step, and disassembly does not get re-popped-up. If I just dismiss the disassembly, it pops-up again on the next step.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint in the source code and run to it. Then you can step in the source code level.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose the the editor window (put your mouse on the editor window then left click) then single stepping is through the source code. However, if you choose the the disassembly window (put your mouse on the disassembly window then left click) then single stepping goes through every assembly instruction.